# Jquery animate rotation not working

Tags: jquery, rotation, jquery-animate

Hi I have this set of code that should rotate an icon at a certain position but it doesnt work can someone help me, this is my js code :

```
<script>
    window.setTimeout(function(){
    $( "#CDT492" ).animate({ "left": "+=212px" ,"top":"+=134px"}, 100000,"linear","alternate",{duration:10,queue: false,
    step: function(left) {
                if (left >= 11) { // stop at ~70
                    $("#CDT492").css('-webkit-transform','rotate(148deg)');
                }
            } }
        );
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

it's more like this animation [animation style](http://atcradarsim.com/simulator/klga/ground)

Comment: Specify whether to rotate in 360 degrees(in 3d) or in 2d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can u do like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   window.setTimeout(function(){
    $( "#CDT492" ).animate({ 
                        "left": "+=212px" 
                        ,"top":"+=134px"
                    },{
    step: function(now) {
                if (now >= 11) {
                    $("#CDT492").css({'transform':'rotate(148deg)','transition':'all ease 1s',});
                }
            } }
        );
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: it does rotate now but I still need to keep the animation in a straight line and move ahead the rotation

Comment: I somehow need to make like this type of transition in the positions [link](http://atcradarsim.com/simulator/klga/ground)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do but it looks like you're trying to move the image as well as rotate it. If you're prepared to use CSS3 transitions then you can just set the css values to what you what them to finish as, and then use a transition. See the following fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqus4swc/).

Whilst this works, I don't think it's great to be setting individual CSS properties in javascript if you can avoid it, so it might be better to define a class (for example we could call it `.rotated`) and then set the class using jquery `$("#CDT492").addClass('rotated')`. (Like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqus4swc/1/))

If you want to start the rotation *after* it has already started moving, you can add a delay to the rotation part of your transition. See here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqus4swc/2/)

Comment: I'm trying to rotate the image after it reaches a certain position.

Comment: You could work out how long the delay needs to be to rotate it at the desired position (maybe using trial and error). 

Does it need to be that accurate? See the third fiddle in the original answer, the 4th part of the `-webkit-transform 5s linear 5s;` is the delay in starting the rotate animation.

So in the above case the duration of the animation is 5s and the delay in starting it is 5s. For the movement the overall duration is 10s. You can play around with the two timings (as long as they sum to 10) to get the rotation to begin at the desired position.

Comment: You can actually probably calculate how long the delay should be (if you are using a linear animation) quite simply

Answer (score 0):

you need to be more specific about what kind of transformation you want , because you've said you want rotation and then after checking the link it's more about transforming the position.